# Ruby merge arrays without duplicates then use higher value out of duplicate array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

i'm working on a version control system in which chef cookbook version numbers are specified in multiple different environments.

I've been able to merge the two environment files together using this format --

```
source      = JSON.parse(File.read("A.json"))
destination = JSON.parse(File.read("B.json"))
source      = destination.merge(source)
```

The values of each file are in this format --

'A'

```
{
  "a": "v2.0.18",
  "b": "v5.0.2",
  "c": "v17.0.0",
  "d": "v9.0.0",
}
```

'B'

```
{
  "a": "v1.0.18",
  "b": "v4.0.0",
  "c": "v20.0.0",
  "d": "v7.0.0"
}
```

Currently does --

```
{
  "a": "v2.0.18",
  "b": "v5.0.2",
  "c": "v17.0.0",
  "d": "v9.0.0",
}
```

What i'd like it to do --

```
{
  "a": "v2.0.18",
  "b": "v5.0.2",
  "c": "v20.0.0", #keeps higher value
  "d": "v9.0.0",
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Chef cookbook versions are simply `x.y.z`, without a leading "v".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge), but you also need to define how the comparison is made between two strings.

`major_minor` converts `"v2.0.18"` to `[2,0,18]`, which can be compared to other version arrays to find the maximum.

```
source = {
  "a": "v2.0.18",
  "b": "v5.0.2",
  "c": "v17.0.0",
  "d": "v9.0.0",
}

destination = {
  "a": "v1.0.18",
  "b": "v4.0.0",
  "c": "v20.0.0",
  "d": "v7.0.0"
}

def major_minor(version)
  version.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
end

p source.merge(destination){|key, old, new| [old, new].max_by{|v| major_minor(v) } }
#=> {:a=>"v2.0.18", :b=>"v5.0.2", :c=>"v20.0.0", :d=>"v9.0.0"}
```

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks, updated. Do you happen to know why `Array#<=>` is defined, but not `Array#>` or `Array#<` ?

Comment: According to [Matz](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5574#note-7): _"Since arrays are not always compatible, I don't want to give wrong implication by making arrays comparable.
Adding <=> was a realistic compromise for me to allow array sorting."_

Comment: Wunderbar, danke!

Answer (score 5):

[Hash#`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) is what you're looking for:

```
a.merge(b) do |key, old_val, new_val|
  Gem::Version.new(old_val[1..-1]) > Gem::Version.new(new_val[1..-1]) ? old_val : new_val
end
#=> {:a=>"v2.0.18", :b=>"v5.0.2", :c=>"v20.0.0", :d=>"v9.0.0"}
```

As [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) suggested, the above could be improved by incorporating the approach **@Eric Duminil**  used [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41721654/1772830):

```
a.merge(b) { |key, *values| values.max_by { |v| Gem::Version.new(v[1..-1]) } }
```

Comment: `old` => `old_val`. Nice use of `Gem::Version`!

Comment: Nice, although I'd incorporate Eric Duminil's approach: `a.merge(b) { |key, *values| values.max_by { |v| Gem::Version.new(v[1..-1]) } }`

Comment: @Stefan, I can't get tired of repeating: you are cool as hell! Absolutely great improvement of what I've written. Will edit

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use [merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) passing a block to choose which value should be chosen when the key is duplicated.

Comment: Upvoted. You were the first to answer, and your answer is technically correct. The OP didn't write any code, it's okay to give hints IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome, based on your question I assumed you needed a hint and you would be able to tie up the details

Answer (score -1):

`merge` takes additional argument block to figure out which key to keep in case both hashes has same key

```
a = {
      "a": "v2.0.18",
      "b": "v5.0.2",
      "c": "v17.0.0",
      "d": "v9.0.0",
    }
b = {
      "a": "v1.0.18",
      "b": "v4.0.0",
      "c": "v20.0.0",
      "d": "v7.0.0"
  }
c = a.merge(b) {|k, v1, v2| [v1, v2].max}
 => {:a=>"v2.0.18", :b=>"v5.0.2", :c=>"v20.0.0", :d=>"v9.0.0"}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Lexicographic order isn't version order. `"v11.0" > "v9.0" #=> false`

Comment: Note: I didn't downvote. I typically just write comments and wait for the answer to get corrected.

Comment: @EricDuminil fair point. I'm too used to work with numbers and it worked just find for this case, but it surely can cause troubles.